# How to create Server.js file in React Setup

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I am looking to retain all current features of express server while adding a way to test my asynchronous validation in server.js . More explanation below

I created react/redux setup using `create-react-app` (just initial) setup and by default the server runs at http://localhost:3000 , I am looking to work on Asynchronous validations.

I tried editing `package.json` file to use the server.js file I created so I changed

```
From  `"start": "react-scripts start"`

TO `"start": "node server.js",`
```

But this disables hot reloading feature

Content of package.json 
     `{
      "name": "signup",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "react": "^16.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
        "react-redux": "^5.0.5",
        "redux": "^3.7.0",
        "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
        "react-scripts": "1.1.1",
        "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
        "express": "^4.16.2"
      },
      "scripts": {
        "start": "node server.js",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
      }
    }`

Comment: Are you using any testing framework? You haven't said how you are trying to test the async portion of server.js.  You might want to look at using Jest or one of the other testing frameworks. Jest can be found at https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/tutorial-react.html with a description how to test with react apps

Comment: No testing framework , Temporarily I will be testing it certain set of rules , once app goes live I will be removing the Async validation using server.js, Just like [https://redux-form.com/6.7.0/examples/asyncvalidation/](redux-form) is validating username but using server.js

Comment: Jest is included in the create-react-app for testing purposes if you want to read up on it. Otherwise, what is your plan to test, start up server.js using node separate from the react app?

Comment: [npm run eject](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#npm-run-eject)

Comment: I was thinking something like retain current setup and in server.js file I can add a check on route and post request
router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
    const { iban } = req.body;